# How to store encrypted notes in a public git repository?

Tags: encryption, defense, git

I save my notes in a git repository in plaintext (markdown). Currently, the remote repository is another computer in my appartment. I am thinking about moving this remote repository to a remote server.

Description:

- I want this to be as simple as possible. As few external tools as possible.

  - Because of this, i don't want to use [git-crypt](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt), since it is very complex and I don't understand it good enough.
  - I also don't want to use [git annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/encryption/) for the very same reason.
- The gitignore file of this repository would ignore *every* file besides `*.asc` files.
- To increase the simplicity I will not obfuscate the filename of the encrypted file. I plan to just be cautious about the filename and not put sensitive stuff inside the file.
- The encryption and decryption would be done with an asymmetric key, and this very asymmetric key would be also included in the repostiory, AES256 encrpyted.
- Maybe, I could also sign each commit with the asymmetric key which lies encrypted in the repository itself. That would prevent an attacker to manipulate something. But I also don't know if it is worth to do that?
- As my laptop has disk encryption, I don't care about plaintext files lying around in this repo (because I edit stuff inside, read them, etc.)
- Being a git repository, I could mirror it to multiple remote repositories.

For that, I have three questions:

1. Is this safe? Obviously random people will have access to my remote repository. Of course, I could make the repository private and not use github, gitlab or something like that - but the sysadmin of the server will have access to this repo, no matter what.

   - At least, I am not competent enough to, for instance, encrypt the filesystem in such a way that I can confidently say that this remote repository will be secure.
2. What key algorithms should I use? Should I use ed25519 (which I trust the most out of ECC's at the moment - although I just superficially read about it) Or should i use RSA 4096 or even bigger?
3. I do not know if I should use gpg2 or [rage](https://github.com/str4d/rage)?

   - I dislike the complexity of gpg, but rage is a very young project. (And I dislike Golang, therefore I also dislike to use the its reference implementation [age](https://github.com/FiloSottile/age).)
   - I will never need the legacy options of gpg, so i will always be able to use version 2+.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer would be to use a symmetric cipher (e.g. AES).

- You are the only user, so you only have to keep the AES key securely stored.
- Symmetrical algorithms are [generally faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/118503/7246232) than asymmetrical ones (but probably not by much for text though).
- You use only one operation at encryption/decryption time.

Now for your questions:

> 1. Is this safe?

AES is still considered safe, but you have to take care with its mode and size. Regarding your use case, you should go with AES-256-CBC, as it might be easier to use than AES-256-GCM and more common than some recent ciphers.

> 2. What key algorithms should I use?

Well, as I said, symmetric only should do the trick.

> 3. I do not know if I should use `gpg2` or `rage`?

OpenSSL could be use for AES (or many other ciphers), some example [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/60713).